# Audio output balance problem

Tags: 10.04, alsa, soundcard

I have a problem on my Ubuntu 10.04 machine with audio output. When playing audio with a headset connected it can be heard on speakers and headset in the same time. It is similar to other questions I found on internet. But what is different is that when I change channel balance to left then only speaker is used. When I changed it to the right only headset is used. It looks like speaker is treated as left channel and headset as the right channel.

[image]

My machine is a custom build Intel Atom based PC.
Audio driver snd-intel8x0
Some additional information:

```
dddd@dddd:~$ lspci | grep audio
00:1e.2 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)

dddd@dddd:/proc/asound$ cat /proc/asound/version 
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.23.
Compiled on Apr 21 2011 for kernel 2.6.32-32-generic-pae (SMP).

dddd@dddd:/proc/asound$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ICH7 [Intel ICH7], device 0: Intel ICH [Intel ICH7]
Subdevices: 0/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ICH7 [Intel ICH7], device 4: Intel ICH - IEC958 [Intel ICH7 - IEC958]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

00:1e.2 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) AC'97   Audio Controller (rev 02)
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    I/O ports at cc00 [size=64]
    Memory at fe93b800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
    Memory at fe93b400 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: Intel ICH
    Kernel modules: snd-intel8x0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this:

Go to terminal: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gnome-terminal`

Type: `alsamixer` and press <kbd>F5</kbd> Now play around with the several bars. You can press <kbd>M</kbd> to mute and Key Up/Down to change the Bar value. To the right of the bars there are more bars depending on your sound card so do not hesitate when changing from bar to bar to keep pressing Key Left/Right to keep on going to the right or left so you can see the rest of the bars.

alsamixer helps in several cases.