# Ubuntu changes speaker balance uncontrolled

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Every now and then the speaker balance of my notebook running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS to the right side. There are no special keyboard shortcuts for that on my notebook and it doesn't happen inattentively.

Does Ubuntu have any shortcuts for that, which I could have pressed accidentally?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of [this old question](https://askubuntu.com/q/46410/349837). Do you get any relevant output with `journalctl -p err | grep -i audio` when happens? Might be useful if you add to your question the output of ` inxi -SMA -xxx -! 31 -y 80`

Comment: Got the same issue. Haven't found a clue yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use this command:

```
amixer sset Master 50%,50%
```

to balance speaker equally. If balance problem persists, you can add this command at startup execution.

Based on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/317296/setting-audio-balance-from-command-line) question